# Получить данные из json golang: декодировать массивы с разнородными данными

Tags: json, golang, struct

Сам ответ json имеет такую структуру:

```json
{
   "payload":[
      0,
      [
         [
            [
               {
                  "title":"Привет!"
               },
               {
                  "title":"123"
               }
            ]
         ],
         1000
      ]
   ]
}
```

Для получения данных я использовал следующий код:

```go
var d map[string]interface{}
rawData := []byte(`{"payload": [0, [[[{"title": "Привет!"}, {"title": "123"}]], 1000]]}`)
err := json.Unmarshal(rawData, &d)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(d["payload"].([]interface{})[1].([]interface{})[0].([]interface{}))
```

Да, этот код работает. Проблема заключается в том, что хотелось бы работать с помощью структур или сделать код более читабельным. На сайте генерации из json в struct ответ следующий. Только не знаю как работать с индексами.

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Payload []interface{} `json:"payload"`
}
```

Comment: так как у вас объекты то integer, то массив данных - их нельзя абсолютно точно описать в виде строгой структуры. поэтому нужно идти через interface

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В go по-умолчанию структуры транслируются в объекты json и обратно. Например, для типа

```
type Title struct {
    Title string `json:"title"` // Use default json codec
}
```

вызов `json.Marshal(Title{"Привет!"})` сгенерирует строку `{"title":"Привет!"}`, а обратное преобразование будет работать через анализ типов:

```go
    var jsonData := []byte(`{"title":"Привет!"}`)
    var dst Title
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &dst)
    ...
```

Но для того, чтобы отобразить структуру в массив и обратно, нужно делать кастомный кодек.

Для приведённого вами примера `json` объекта я придумал вот такую иерархию типов:

```go
type Message struct {
    Payload OuterArray `json:"payload"` // Use default json codec
}

type OuterArray struct {
    Number int
    Data   InnerArray
}

type InnerArray struct {
    Titles []ArrayOfTitles
    Number int
}

type ArrayOfTitles []Title // Use default json codec

type Title struct {
    Title string `json:"title"` // Use default json codec
}
```

Для структур `OuterArray` и `InnerArray` нужно делать кастомные кодеки. Маршалер устроен просто:

```
// Implements json.Marshaler
func (ia InnerArray) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    asArray := []interface{}{
        ia.Titles,
        ia.Number,
    }
    return json.Marshal(asArray)
}

// Implements json.Marshaler
func (oa OuterArray) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    asArray := []interface{}{
        oa.Number,
        oa.Data,
    }
    return json.Marshal(asArray)
}
```

Анмаршалер устроен хитрее. В `encoding/json` есть потоковый парсер, который позволяет парсить json токен за токеном. Соответственно, нужно проверить, что первый токен - это открывающая скобка `[`, затем парсить элементы массива в соответствии со структурой.

```
// Implements json.Unmarshaler
func (dst *OuterArray) UnmarshalJSON(bytes []byte) error {
    stream := string(bytes)
    dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(stream))
    // read open bracket
    token, err := dec.Token()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    delim, ok := token.(json.Delim)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("Not an array: %s", stream)
    }
    if delim != '[' {
        return fmt.Errorf("'[' expected, got: %c", delim)
    }

    if !dec.More() {
        return fmt.Errorf("Missing number: %s", string(bytes))
    }
    err = dec.Decode(&dst.Number)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if !dec.More() {
        return fmt.Errorf("Missing data: %s", string(bytes))
    }
    err = dec.Decode(&dst.Data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

В результате кодирование/декодирование работает без проблем:

```
var msg = `{
    "payload":[
       0,
       [
          [
             [
                {
                   "title":"Привет!"
                },
                {
                   "title":"123"
                }
             ]
          ],
          1000
       ]
    ]
 }`


func main() {
    ia := InnerArray{
        Titles: []ArrayOfTitles{
            {
                Title{Title: "Привет!"},
                Title{Title: "123"},
            },
        },
        Number: 1000,
    }

    oa := OuterArray{
        Number: 0,
        Data:   ia,
    }

    payload := Message{
        Payload: oa,
    }

    bytes, err := json.Marshal(payload)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Object: %#v\nEncoded: %s\n", payload, string(bytes))

    var msgDecoded Message

    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(msg), &msgDecoded)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Decoded object: %#v\n", msgDecoded)
}
```

Результат работы программы:

```
Object: main.Message{Payload:main.OuterArray{Number:0, Data:main.InnerArray{Titles:[]main.ArrayOfTitles{main.ArrayOfTitles{main.Title{Title:"Привет!"}, main.Title{Title:"123"}}}, Number:1000}}}
Encoded: {"payload":[0,[[[{"title":"Привет!"},{"title":"123"}]],1000]]}
Decoded object: main.Message{Payload:main.OuterArray{Number:0, Data:main.InnerArray{Titles:[]main.ArrayOfTitles{main.ArrayOfTitles{main.Title{Title:"Привет!"}, main.Title{Title:"123"}}}, Number:1000}}}
```

Как видите, кодирование работает в обе стороны. Вместо `d["payload"].([]interface{})[1].([]interface{})[0].([]interface{})` доступ к списку названий будет `msgDecoded.Payload.Data.Titles`

Полный вариант кода со всем необходимыми в Github: https://github.com/pakuula/StackOverflow/blob/main/go/1436064/main.go

Comment: хороший ответ !